# Rerun Excel macro when data gets updated

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that hides rows if a cell in a specific column contains a 0 value.

I have found a macro from another forum to use that will hide the rows (below) but it will only hide rows the first time the data gets refreshed. I am using data validation cells at the top of the sheet that pulls in data from another sheet to populate reference data (and the rest of the sheet uses SUMIFS).

When my team updates the cell to select various options (Ex: USA, Asia, Europe, All), I need the macro to run again to hide any cells that contain a 0 value. I also can't have a macro that will mess with the SUMIFS formulas being used in the sheet.

Current formula I have:

```
Sub HideRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

For Each c In Range("E7:E153")
    If c.Value = 0 Then Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
Next

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I think all I need is to add some sort of rerun or loop lines at the end but am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TYVM.

Comment: "...hide any cells that contains a 0 value". Do you want to hide that row? Column? Or literally just that cell? You can't exactly (AFAIK) hide a single cell...but perhaps we can "hide" it by making the text white, or something?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Worksheet_Change event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlManual

        For Each c In Range("E7:E153")
            If c.Value = 0 Then Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True Else Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False
        Next

        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, 
This has the same issue as before - It isn't unhiding the rows following the previous data filter. 
Alter, not a requirement, but the macro executes only when I click into a cell following the data refresh. That's ok but is there a way for it to do it on it's own?

Comment: Try adding Else Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False. I updated my answer above.

Comment: @K Paul It works! Thank you! Any idea if there's a way to make it so that you don't have to click out to get the macro to execute again (aka unhide/hide the rows)?

Comment: Use Worksheet_Change event instead of Worksheet_SelectionChange

Comment: Duh @GordonBell, I'm losing it over here. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. This works like a charm. Have a wonderful Thursday/Weekend

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox "You just changed " & Target.Address

End Sub
```

borrowed from **http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm**

Just Reference target.Address to the specific cells that chages, and then have it call `HideRows`

If you need to unhide all rows before hand just add this code to your procedure `ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False`

Comment: @KPaul Does it matter? If target.Address changes and it calls his sub, then the end result is still attained. The point was to illustrate how to use the worksheet_change event. Not mention I never actually said anywhere to hide the rows. I said "then have it call the hideRows" sub which is the name of his sub that does the work. Basic OOP if you seperate the worksheet change form the hide rows sub (which is something that should probably be done in the first place, lol)

Comment: Hi @KPaul BruceWayne and DougCoats Thank you so much for the help. I tried the macro you provided and it works the first time you filter the data but, if you were to filter to more options, it doesn't clear the hidden rows.

Ex: If I were to filter by Europe and then back to All and then by sales person, the hidden rows from the previous filter never un-hid. Therefore, by the time I was roughly 3 data updates in, I had no rows left.

Is there an update that can be made so that the hidden rows from 1 filter become unhidden/irrelevant for the next data refresh?

Thanks, again!

Comment: Maybe the macro can be to fill all cells a certain color that contain a 0 and then I can use the filter option to filter by color - Would that work?

Comment: @bgreen I have updated my answer to show you how to unhide everything.